# User Authentication with Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, doorkeeper

I have two Rails apps, and I would like to accept user login credentials from one app (say App A) in another (say App B).  For the app that's accepting login credentials (App B), I think the best option is to use OAuth.  But for the app whose user credentials are being used (App A), how do I allow the user's login information to be used by another site?  Do I use OAuth as well, or something like [Doorkeeper](https://github.com/applicake/doorkeeper)?  As you can tell, I'm very new to user authentication, so any advice would be helpful!

Comment: I think you need SSO, [Multiple Applications with Devise, Omniauth and Single Sign On](http://blog.joshsoftware.com/2010/12/16/multiple-applications-with-devise-omniauth-and-single-sign-on/)

Answer (score 5):

One possible way to solve the problem is to create a doorkeeper-based standalone app that would contain all of a user's credentials. Then your client apps would actually connect with this "auth app" (using Oauth.) Then when the client is authenticated on the Auth App, they get returned to the Client app. Of course, from a UI perspective, you make this seamless, so your login page would actually be on this Auth app, but it would look seamless to the user. This way, you can add as many apps as you want and the credentials would all be in one place. To answer your specific question, you would use Oauth2 on your Client apps and Doorkeeper on your Auth App.

You'll need to tweak the doorkeeper configurations to make this process "clean" to the user. For example for internal apps, you can safely use the `skip_authorization` method in doorkeeper. [Learn more about that here](https://github.com/applicake/doorkeeper/wiki/Skipping-application-authorization)

This doorkeeper/oauth system has the added benefit of decoupling your authentication logic from your main application, which is fundamental to good Service Oriented Design. There are certainly other ways to approach this problem, but given the context of your question, yes, Doorkeeper and Oauth2 would solve your problem.